# I have this code in C about union; how did we get the result 1101?

Tags: c

I have this code in C about union; how did we get the result 1101? How do we count the number of bits?

```
#include "stdio.h"

union data {
    struct Bits {
        unsigned int x1:1;
        unsigned int x2:1;
        unsigned int x3:1;
        unsigned int x4:1;
    } bits;
    int y:4;
};

void main(){
    union data d1;
    d1.y =13;
    printf("%d%d%d%d", d1.bits.x4, d1.bits.x3, d1.bits.x2, d1.bits.x1);
    char c = getc(stdin);
}
```

Comment: If you wrote the code yourself: What result do you think you should get instead? Why? If someone else wrote it: where did it come from? What does *that source* tell you about the meaning of the code? If someone gave you the code without explanation, you should *ask that person*.

Comment: What is 13 expressed in binary form?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this code from my programming languages course and the slides just give me this example about union in C, with no further explanation.

Comment: @AdrianMole ohh I got it now, basically, it will give me the number 13 in binary which is 1101. Thank you so much, Adrian!!

Comment: @Luigi Beware that it is probably not guaranteed that this code will print 1101. The order in which bitfields are assigned is implementation defined.  I think it's possible this code could print 1011, or perhaps 0000.

Comment: @SteveSummit I did run the code on ideone and the result was 1101

Comment: @Luigi Sure.  But that doesn't mean it's guaranteed to give 1101 everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

How bit-fields are stored in the memory is implementation defined.

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
> enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that
> immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed
> into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
> whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or
> overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of
> allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or
> low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of
> the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

> I did run the code on ideone and the result was 1101

It does not guarantee that other compilers will not generate a completely different result. gcc for example follows the particular ABI

> The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (C90 6.5.2.1, C99
> and C11 6.7.2.1).
>
> ```
> Determined by ABI.
> ```

> The alignment of non-bit-field members of
> structures (C90 6.5.2.1, C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).
>
> ```
>  Determined by ABI.
> ```